# Jersey framework registering package using @ApplicationPath("/") not working

Tags: java, rest, tomcat7, jersey-2.0

I am new to restful service and trying to learn using jersey framework.
I am using jersey version 2.14, Tomcat 7.
I am not using web.xml file, so I am registering rest class packages using `@ApplicationPath("/")` annotation.

The code is as follows,

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        System.out.println("Registering packages");
        packages("com.sap.earchive.rest.service");
    }
}
```

And rest class is having a simple test code....

```
@Path("/archive")
public class ArchiveService {


    @Path("/test")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

but when ever I try to call url http://localhost:8080/EArchive9/archive/test using postman I am getting 404 error.

I added a log statement "Registering packages" but i am not seeing this in tomcat logfile or console.

I think I am missing something. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: 1. `/archive`? You do not have that on your `@ApplicationPath`
2. You should add `@Provider` to your `ArchiveService` class

Comment: Adding to what @nobeh said, while I'm not very used to the `@ApplicationPath` annotation, but when using the webxml, the Jersey resource path parameter is usually ended with a wildcard. Your original example would look like `@ApplicationPath('/*')` and if you wanted to access your 'test' service endpoint under the 'archive' path provided, it might look like `@ApplicationPath('/archive/*')`.

Comment: I have @Path("/archive") for ArchiveService. I think i missed while copying. I have added it now.Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have the `jersey-container-servlet` jar/dependency.

Comment: I used maven to create the jersey project,so it included all the required jars....I tried by adding wildcard(*), this also din't help :(. I added System.out.println("Registering packages"); it never got called, so it means MyApplication class never got called....Do I have to add anyother annotations to thsi class?